# Passing a value while writing inside a file:C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to pass the value of one of the variables(containing the value of a path) to the contents of the file I am writing. The file outfile is of type ".ctl"

Lets say the file "outfile.ctl" gets created at location /abc/xyz
so I will be having /abc/xyz/outfile.ctl at this location. Now inside outfile.ctl file I have written some context. If you see the contents carefully I have included the line:  file <<"file='filepath/Trial.data'\n"; which creates another file with the name Trial.data in the location filepath.Lets says filepath = /pqr/stu. So Ideally after the outfile.ctl file compiles I should have trial.data created at /pqr/stu llocation. I want to achieve this by the system command. But not getting the desired result created.Elaborated code is below
Snippet of the code.

```cpp
void somefunc()
{
    fstream file_1;
    char outfile1[120],
        filename[50] = "/abc/xyz/outfile.ctl";
    char filepath[50] = "/pqr/stu/;
        strcpy(outfile1, filename);
    cout << outfile1;
    cout << "\n";
    file_1.open(outfile1, ios::out);
    if (file_1) {
        file_1 << "export\n";
        file_1 << "client=000\n";
        file_1 << "file='" << filepath << "/Trial.data'\n";
        file_1 << "delete from BDRGIN\n";
        file_1 << "select * from BDRGIN\n";
        file_1.close();
        system("R3trans outfile1");
    }
```

Ideally the last line should create the trial data file in /pqr/stu/ folder but it doesnt. In my case it doesnot happen so , and a file outfile_1(without file extension) gets created in the folder where I am running the .cpp script. Can someone help?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile

Comment: This is just part of the code, so thats why you cannot compile it.

Comment: As much as we're huge fans of Minimal, Complete and Verifiable are highly recommended. When you have all three and still have a question, it's probably a good question. In this case you've gone too minimal and don't have Complete or Verifiable. What I see here is a program that should create or overwrite a file named outfile, once the missing `"` is added, or a file with the name in the outfile variable once the stray `'` is removed.

Comment: too many unknowns.. but you must ensure that folders down entire path exist. `open` can't create directories. if you use new enough compiler, you might want to look into using C++ filesystem

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie- Open will not create a directory. I think you did not get the question. The issue persists with system command and not open. the problem is whenever Im trying to put the command system( R3trans filepath) it does not recorgnise the filepath which is a variable storing the file path location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a couple of things which I added:

*You didn't include the output filename and filepath variables into your code, you didn't post all of your code to make in compilable.*

Below is the code with "current path" (which we obtain with cwd in Linux) and your filename, included into your file "Trial.data" and written to the "current path/Trial.data" in you compile directory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h> //for strcat to concatinate the two (filepath+filename)
#include <unistd.h> //for getcwd to obtain your 'current path'

using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream file;
    char cwd[256];
    char *filepath= {getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd))}; // or write your path here instead
    char filename[15] = "/Trial.data";
    strcat(filepath, filename);
    file.open(filepath,ios::out);
    if(!file){
        cout<<"File creation failed";
    } else {
            cout<<"New file created";
            file <<"export\n";
            file <<"client=000\n";
            file <<"file='" << filepath << "'\n";
            file <<"select * from   HTTPURLLOC\n";
            file.close(); // Step 5: Closing file
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard

```
file << "file='" << filepath << "/Trial.data'\n";
```

In C++ variables don't get substituted inside strings (unlike some scripting languages).

EDIT

You have basically made the same mistake again with your system command, **variables don't get substituted inside strings**. If you need a string variable which is made from other string variables you have to build up the string using `strcpy` and `strcat`. Try it like this

```
   char cmd[250];
   strcpy(cmd, "R3trans ");
   strcat(cmd, outfile1);
   cout << cmd << "\n"; // for testing
   system(cmd);
```

Comment: Thankyou. However I forgot to add one more thing.

Comment: @user1574187 I've edited my answer to include your latest question.